# Why won't SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe start?

Tags: windows-10, sql-server

I need to install SQL Server Management Studio. I downloaded the setup file then I click on the setup file to install it, but nothing happens.

I tried to open it as administrator. Yet again, nothing happened, except a pop up to give permission. Can someone please give me an answer on how to run the installation?

Comment: Are you sure you have the full file? It’s ~800 MiB. Also, do you have any third-party virus scanners?

Comment: I did absolutly nothing, but after 3 hours it suddenly works.